# MATLAB using UNC-path with credentials

Tags: windows, matlab, unc, network-share, networkcredentials

I need to use an *UNC-Path* within **MATLAB**. As the login *credentials are further needed* and storing on the machine is **not** wanted, I'm looking for a nice way to change into the path.
At the moment I think of this solution

```
try
    cd('\\192.168.175.128\shr');
catch
    system('net use \\192.168.175.128\shr pwd /USER:netusr')
    cd('\\192.168.175.128\shr');
end
```

but I'm looking for better ideas: Maybe there is an integrated function in matlab like `cd_to_unc(path,usr,pwd)` or other integrated solutions? I think, the system-call is a kind of ineffective, isn't it?
Just to make clear - this is not a security related question. I'm only looking for a (maybe) `more efficient` way to do this mount.

Comment: You don't like it because your password is stored in a file in clear text?  Any other reasons?  State your desired improvement.  Also, I added the Windows tag since this is asked as an OS specific question.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is a general-purpose mathematical prototyping IDE (atleast). I do not believe it is meant to have the capabilities you are looking for. The implementation of network access with credentials on LANs is in most cases highly platform-specific and I would assume outside the "scope" of MATLAB.

MATLAB has the standard utilities for creating path-strings that are mostly platform-independent. See [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html), [pathsep](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/pathsep.html), [filesep](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/filesep.html), [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html), etc. But one thing is to create strings with pathnames - another one is to access these path. I believe this is always dependent on the underlying OS. Using `cd` and `system` is likely your only options.

I assume that you could solve this on driver-level and use special URIs with credentials built in (an anology would be FTP credentials in URIs as described in [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)). Security would likely be less optimal. I would be surprised if something like this does not exist already - atleast on linux.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, but I think, you miss one detail: UNC-Paths are mapped in windows and in linux to SMB/CIFS-mounts, which are not platform-specific, as far as I know. I was jsut looking for a `more integrated way` doing that above. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ole - I marked some answer as accepted. I have other accounts on the stackexchange-network, where I have 100% accept-rate. But here, most answer have been not good enough for me to get marked. But for lets say cosmetic reasons I selected them. Back to the question: You are right with your proposition (+1).